# Flutter Web App cannot access the Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-app-check

As I'm in development mode, my Firebase security rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

But beside having the rules public, I'm facing this error.

```
Error: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:7357/dart_sdk.js:5061:11)
    at http://localhost:7357/packages/firebase_core/src/internals.dart.lib.js:81:63
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:7357/dart_sdk.js:38511:59)
    at _FutureListener.catchError.handleError
    (http://localhost:7357/dart_sdk.js:33726:33)
    at handleError (http://localhost:7357/dart_sdk.js:34281:51)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:7357/dart_sdk.js:34307:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeError] (http://localhost:7357/dart_sdk.js:34157:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback
    (http://localhost:7357/dart_sdk.js:34193:31)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:7357/dart_sdk.js:38778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:7357/dart_sdk.js:38784:13)
    at http://localhost:7357/dart_sdk.js:34519:9
```

Stuck. Help please!
Note: I have also tried *allow read, write: if true;*

Comment: Try this (without semicolons): `allow read, write: if true`

Comment: It didn't help. I have tried the same but no vain...

Comment: Maybe you have App Check enabled?

Comment: @PeterKoltai Yes.. This was the problem. You can post this as answer.

Comment: Good to hear, I was just having a similar issue with App Check, that's why it came to my mind as a possible cause.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Peter Koltai, enablement of App check is the issue here.
The support for App Check to Firestore was recently added, for more details [check here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/11/whats-new-at-Firebase-Summit-2021.html#Strengthening).