# Firestore rule to access subcollection raising Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am struggling with Firestore rules to allow access to some resources in a subcollection.

I have some `requests` documents, that may present a sub-collection named `status`. My current rules are something like that:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    // I use it to check if user is signed in
    function userSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
    
    match /requests/{requestId} {
        
      // I use it to check if user is the owner of the request
      function userCanAccess () {
        return userSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/requests/$(requestId)).data.userId;
      }
      
      
      // allow read to logged user who own request
      allow read, update: if userCanAccess();
      
      // anyone can create a new request
      allow create: if true;
      
      // no one can delete the request
      allow delete: if false;
      
      
      
      match /status/{statusId} {
        // allow read and update of status to logged user who own request
        allow read, update: if userCanAccess();
        
        // anyone can create the status
        allow create: if true;
        
        // no one can delete the status
        allow delete: if false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My very first way to check if user had access was by `request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId`, however it only works for `requests` documents, not for `status` documents since they do not have the `userId` field.

I'm using flutter to make the request with the code:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('requests')
            .where('userId', isEqualTo: user.uid)
            .orderBy('requestedOn', descending: true)
            .snapshots()
            .listen((snapshot) {
              // Here I read requests and their status
            });
```

However I'm getting `Error: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] Missing or insufficient permissions.`. How can I solve (or debug) it? Using rules playground in firestore, with the exact same `uid`, I am able to complete the reading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the `get()` call may be causing problems. Try this:

```
function userCanAccess () {
  return userSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == requestId.data.userId;
}
```

Comment: This may not be used as-is: `Invalid type. There is no type for variable 'requestId' that satisfies all clauses.`

Comment: Have you tried to debug it with the [Firestore Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator)? Also, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70321779/flutter-web-app-cannot-access-the-firebase-cloud-firestore), you can verify if AppCheck is enabled. Meanwhile, you could try any of the following [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590155/firestore-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions).